# Yahoo Finance, Meteor and sessions

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, helper, yahoo-finance

I am trying to output stock information from yahoo finance with Meteor. It was working before but I have been away from the project for a while. I have updated meteor so I am thinking something may have been broken during the update. This is the package I am using.
https://atmospherejs.com/ajbarry/yahoo-finance

I am successfully grabbing the data from yahoo but it doesn't seem to pass into a session and I can't output the objects data in the template.

This is a my client javascript code.

```
Template.stock.rendered = function (){
    // if ( _.isEmpty(Session.get('ENW.V')) ) {
        Meteor.call('getQuote', 'ENW.V', function(err, result) {
            Session.set('ENW.V', result['ENW.V']);
            console.log(result);
        });
    // }


        if ( _.isEmpty(Session.get('E4U.F')) ) {
            Meteor.call('getQuote', 'E4U.F', function(err, result) {
                Session.set('E4U.F', result['E4U.F']);
                console.log(result);
            });
        }

};

Template.stock.helpers({
    stock: function() {
        return Session.get('ENW.V');
    },
    stock2: function() {
        return Session.get('E4U.F');
    }
});
```

This is the stock html template

```
<template name="stock">

<div class="container">
  {{> header}}
</div>

{{>investorsSubNav}}

{{> sidebar}}


<div class="investorsWrap">
<div class="investorsBody">
  <section class="stockBodyHero">

    <div class="stockLeft">    
      <div class="stockCenter"> 
        <h2>Enwave Corporation TSX</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Symbol</strong>{{stock.symbol}}</li>
          <li><strong>Market Cap</strong> $ {{stock.marketCapitalization}}</li>
          <li><strong>Average Daily Volume</strong> $ {{stock.averageDailyVolume}}</li>
          <li><strong>52 Week Low</strong> $ {{stock.[52WeekLow]}}</li>
          <li><strong>52 Week High</strong> $ {{stock.[52WeekHigh]}}</li>
          <li><strong>Change</strong> {{stock.change}}</li>   
        </ul>
      </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="stockRight">
      <div class="stockCenter">
        <h2>Enwave Corporation FSE</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Symbol</strong> {{stock2.symbol}} </li>
          <li><strong>Market Cap</strong> $ {{stock2.marketCapitalization}}</li>
          <li><strong>Average Daily Volume</strong> $ {{stock2.averageDailyVolume}}</li>
          <li><strong>52 Week Low</strong> $ {{stock2.[52WeekLow]}}</li>
          <li><strong>52 Week High</strong> $ {{stock2.[52WeekHigh]}}</li>
        </ul>   
      </div>    
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

this is the server side method

```
Meteor.methods({
  getQuote: function( stockname ) {
    return YahooFinance.snapshot({symbols: [stockname] , fields:['n','a','b','j1','a2','k','j','c1'] });
  }
});
```

This is the format of the object when it is console logged
[image]

Comment: Can you try `$ meteor add ejson` - this is a previously standard package that is not in 1.2 by default. It may relate to your object not making it into the Session variable.

Comment: I had already installed ejson before. This was returned in terminal when i ran meteor update again `babrahams:editable-json 0.4.3 (0.6.1 is available)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package. Can you console.log the session variables right after you set them?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. They return undefined. So I know thats where the problem lies. But don't know why exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I think I see the problem. Let's focus on ENW.V:

You're setting:

```
Session.set('ENW.V', result['ENW.V']);
```

And your `console.log(result)` is returning:

```
stock.js:5 [Object]0:
  Object
    52WeekHigh: 1.34
    52WeekLow: 0.69
    ask: 0.89
    averageDailyVolume: 77643
    bid: 0.81
    change: 0.04
    marketCapitalization: "71.84M"
    name: "ENWAVE CORP"
    symbol: "ENW.V"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

If that output is correct then there is no `ENW.V` key and `result[ENW.V']` will be undefined.

Yahoo is returning an array of objects of length 1. I suggest the following changes to your helpers and templates:

```
Template.stock.rendered = function (){
  Meteor.call('getQuote', 'ENW.V', function(err, result) {
    Session.set('ENW.V', result[0]); // extract the first element of the array
    console.log(result);
    console.log(Session.get('ENW.V')); // double check
  });
  Meteor.call('getQuote', 'E4U.F', function(err, result) {
    Session.set('E4U.F', result[0]);
            console.log(result);
}

Template.stock.helpers({
  stock: function(symbol) { // this avoids having to create one helper/symbol
    return Session.get(symbol);
  }
});
```

**html:**

```
<template name="stock">
<div class="investorsWrap">
  <div class="investorsBody">
    <section class="stockBodyHero">
      <div class="stockLeft">    
        {{#with stock 'ENW.V'}}
          {{> oneStock}}
        {{/with}}    
      </div>   
      <div class="stockRight">
        {{#with stock 'E4U.F'}}
        {{> oneStock}}
        {{/with}}
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<template name="oneStock">
<div class="stockCenter"> 
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Symbol</strong>{{symbol}}</li>
    <li><strong>Market Cap</strong> $ {{marketCapitalization}}</li>
    <li><strong>Average Daily Volume</strong> $ {{averageDailyVolume}}</li>
    <li><strong>52 Week Low</strong> $ {{this.[52WeekLow]}}</li>
    <li><strong>52 Week High</strong> $ {{this.[52WeekHigh]}}</li>
    <li><strong>Change</strong> {{change}}</li>   
  </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ok, what should i do to access the `Object` and set in in the Session? I swear it had this key before, I assume something in the yahoo-finance package updated.

Comment: I think that `Session.set('ENW.V', result);` should be sufficient. It looks like you only have one object in there. Double check in the inspector to see exactly what the internal structure is.

Comment: This is the format of the object console logged. http://i.stack.imgur.com/9DRW1.png The template helpers I have setup simply are not returning anything.